# Array-based Trie Implementation. Non-null value in the child array

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I'm trying to understand the array-based implementation of Trie from http://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-implement-trie-prefix-tree-java/ (see Java Solution 2 - Improve Performance by Using an Array).

```
public void insert(String word) {
    TrieNode p = root;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        int index = c - 'a';
        if(p.arr[index] == null) {
            TrieNode temp = new TrieNode();
            p.arr[index] = temp;
            p = temp;
        } else {
            p = p.arr[index];
        }
    }
    p.isEnd = true;
}
```

I'm not sure the else branch is ever executed. What am I missing?

**Update 1**

The given word only contains lower-case English letters

Comment: Side comment: `int index = c-'a';` is totally wrong.  For uppercase letters, digits, spaces and many punctuation characters this produces a negative number.

Comment: @Jim, please see update 1

Comment: Where's the source for `TrieNode`?

Comment: @Jim, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you call this function, the else branch will indeed not execute. However, as the Trie gets populated, it is very possible that `p.arr[index]` is not null.

For example, calling `insert("i")` will cause add a new TrieNode at `root.arr['i' - 'a']`. Calling the function a second time, for example with `insert("it")`, will result in the check `p.arr[index] == null` returning false because the first insert already added the `TrieNode` for `i` at the root node.

You can test this out with the following main function (and putting a breakpoint or println statement in the `else` branch)

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Trie t = new Trie();
    t.insert("i");
    t.insert("it");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me pretty much like a bug. If c-'a'>26 then p.arr[index] won't be null but will raise an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.